# how to overwrite images in gallery

Tags: android, save, gallery

i need to save a bitmap temporarily in my app and pass it's uri to next activity but bundles dose not work because of large size of image and i decided to save it in image gallery and then use this image in next activity but i need this temporarily images overwrite to previous one and in any second i have just one temporarily image,how can i do that?thank you

this is my code for saving in gallery:

```
    frame1=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.finalview);
                    frame1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                    String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                            getContentResolver(),        Bitmap.createBitmap(frame1.getDrawingCache()),
                            UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "تصویر");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save it as a file and use your next activity to load it, specifying a file name for it so you could overwrite it at any time.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html